# Use Azure CLI within Azure Powershell Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-cli

I want to create a Powershell script which executes some `AzureRm...` commands and follows those up with some `Az` commands. Reason being that some commands are only available via `Az`.

When trying to execute these scripts in a release pipeline, the script always fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

Executing the `Az` commands in a `Azure CLI` task work as expected, because `Az Login` is executed by the task.

I don't want to pass the secret required to login to the script if at all possible. I would rather fall back to separating the scripts into two steps in the pipeline.

Is it possible to use the `Az`commands within a `Azure Powershell` task without passing the secrets manually?

### Minimal example:

- Create a new release pipeline
- Add a task `Azure PowerShell`
- Use inline script
- As script, execute `az account show`

Comment: which commands?

Comment: `az cosmosdb list-keys` and the other cosmos commands are required in my case, but `az account show` does not work either

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CosmosDB/2.1.9.95 try this?

Comment: I will take a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short term solution I already had in place was passing the ServicePrincipal information into the powershell script and executing `az login` manually (same as Bevan's answer below).

My long term solution was to replace all Azure CLI calls with "Az Powershell" commands.
Luckily, most commands are available by now.

A couple of commands don't have an equivalent commandlet. But if they are available via ARM, you can figure out an alternative command with Powershell.

Many of them involve using `New-AzResource/New-AzureRmResource` or `Invoke-AzResourceAction/Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction`

- [How to create a Linux AppService Plan with New-AzAppServicePlan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719532/how-to-create-a-linux-appservice-plan-with-new-azappserviceplan)
- [Manage Azure Cosmos DB SQL API resources using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-with-powershell)

```bsh
# AzureCLI
az cosmosdb list-keys
# Powershell:
$keys = Invoke-AzResourceAction -Action listKeys `
    -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $accountName
```

Comment: BTW one can pass `--debug` to an `az` command to find out which exactly API method it calls under the hood. Then, reproduce it with `Invoke-AzResourceAction`.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out this approach - **store credentials in job scoped variables** (currently only an `Azure CLI` task allows that) and then re-use in `Azure PowerShell` task:

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Azure CLI - get credentials'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'SUBSCRIPTIONNAME'
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      inlineScript: |
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]$($env:servicePrincipalId)"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]$($env:servicePrincipalKey)"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]$($env:tenantId)"      

  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'collector'
    inputs:
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
      azureSubscription: 'SUBSCRIPTIONNAME'
      pwsh: true
      scriptType: inlineScript
      inline: |
        az login --service-principal --username "$($env:ARM_CLIENT_ID)" --password "$($env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)" --tenant "$($env:ARM_TENANT_ID)"
        ./mixedscript.ps1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Now I can run Azure CLI commands in my external PS file.

Answer (score 1):

When I have mixed commands I put this into my Azure Powershell task

`az login --service-principal --username "$(ServicePrincipal)" --password "$(AzureDevOps-ServicePrincipal-Secret)" --tenant "$(Azure_Tenant)"`

I have my SP and Tenant IDs as a variables and the Secret for the SP stored in Azure KeyVault linked to a Library Variable group. You can alternatively just stored the secret in a normal Variable/Variable Group and hit the padlock icon to secure it.

You may need to run `az account set -s $(SubscriptionName)` if the SP has access to multiple subscriptions in the same tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, it wont work like that, because you have to authenticate to az utility separately. az cli and powershell do not share connection information. you can try and use az step with some command before powershell step. that would force az to auth and after that you can use it inside powershell ste.

Comment: Added an inline Azure CLI step with `az account show`, tried to do the same in the powershell task afterwards... did not work